# nodemon is unable to find ts-node in exec-parameter

Tags: node.js, typescript, nodemon, yarnpkg, ts-node

I'm trying to use ts-node with nodemon. Both are installed using yarn and my package.json has the following structure:

```
{
  "name": "yarnTest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.0.36",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/chalk": "^0.4.31",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "ts-node": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec 'ts-node --cache-directory .tscache' ./src/www.ts",
    "start": "ts-node --fast ./dist/www.ts"
  }
}
```

Now, when I use "yarn run dev", it executes nodemon and nodemon tries to execute "ts-node" but nodemon tells me that the command "ts-node" does not exist:

Der Befehl "'ts-node" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden.

Yarn is installed globally but ts-node is installed for my project only.
I already tried:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec 'yarn run ts-node --cache-directory .tscache' ./src/www.ts",
    "start": "ts-node --fast ./dist/www.ts"
  }
```

But this gives me the error that "yarn" is not found :(
Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: How about `"nodemon --exec 'yarn run ts-node --cache-directory .tscache' ./src/www.ts"`?

Comment: Already tried without success. Using this command I'm getting the message that yarn is not found, although yarn is installed globally and available in all other cli's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally solved the issue!
After some hours I figured out that nodemon told me, that it's unable to find "'ts-node" (or "'yarn"). The apostroph was confusing me, so I finally replaced both apostrophes in my package.json with " and now my working script command is the following one:

```
 "dev": "nodemon --exec \"ts-node --cache-directory .tscache\" ./src/www.ts"
```

Answer (score 11):

You should install `ts-node` first, run `npm install -g ts-node`

Answer (score 2):

2020 Update
I am trying to run a typescript file with nodemon and following `dev` script in package.json is sufficient

```
{
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.ts"
}
```

No need of including ts-node in the dev script.

> I have ts-node and nodemon in dependencies